# How can I replace a character in of the middle of a string with a random character?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, replace, insert

I am checking the values of a string that is a unique identifier for a third party service that has some strict rules about the identifier, if a duplicate is generated I need to catch it and replace a character to make it unique.  The Rules: It must be a string, it must be <= 21 characters long, the last four characters are significant and come preset and can't be altered, the first 15 characters are significant come preset and can't be altered, so I only have two characters that I can alter, and finally another third party system sets the string and will gladly duplicate them if the circumstances are right.  They're always right.  like. always... lol

At first I thought of using str.next! but that violates the last four rule.  Then I tried str.insert(-5, rand(9).to_s) That would alter one of the correct characters and make the string unique, but it violates the <=21 characters rule.

```
str = "abcdefghijklmnoXX_123" (I can safely alter the XX)
str.next! (makes it unique but violates last four rule)
str.insert(-5, rand(9).to_s) (alters the correct characters and makes it unique, but violates the str.length rule.
```

How can I replace the correct character set without altering the string length or violating any further rules?  Oh, It is also preferred that I not shorten the string length if possible.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but is there a problem with `str[-5] = rand(9).to_s`?

Comment: Are you saying that it your example you need to change the the three `"X"`'s to three characters that are different from one another and different than all the characters that cannot be altered? Can they be changed to, say, any ASCII character? Are `"w"` and `"W"` treated as different characters? I presume that number of characters that can be changed equals `str.size - 19`. Correct? (Note your example has 22 characters even though you said 21 is the limit. You may wish to answer these questions by editing your question.

Comment: @ggorlen yes.  .insert() adds to the string length and violates the 21char rule.

Comment: I'm not using `insert`. I'm assigning the last of your `X` area to a random digit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the three Xs was a typo (off by one error, lol) I only get to play with two.  I can change any one of the Xs to make the whole unique.  I believe the service is case insensitive so 'w' and 'W' are the same.  Also I have numbers, letters and a few special characters available to me.  Thanks for the questions!

Comment: @ggorlen Ah!  I see that now.  To the console!  Thank you!

Comment: OK, I made a change to my answer to deal with case insensitivity. I think it should be pretty close to your requirements, unless I've misunderstood something. btw, I thought Texans "string" fences, not "build" them..

Comment: @CarySwoveland  HAHA!  Very true but 'build' fit better in context!

Comment: @CarySwoveland  HAHA!  Very true but 'build' fit better in context!  Thanks for your help!  I will have to spend some time deciding how many iterations I might have for these identifiers.  ggorlen's solution's quick and easy for a newb, like me to understand and write while keeping with in Sandi Metz rules.  Which my team has decided they want to follow.  How ever it will only be good for 101 iterations before we have another wreck again.  Only having two characters to play with is going to mean there is a finite number of iterations we can have, which is going to cramp our style eventually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed that the characters being replaced do not have to be random, but simply different from each other and different from all of the other characters in the string. If they are for some reason to be selected randomly, further specificity is required, specifically the collection of characters from which characters are to be drawn randomly. I have a further comment on this at the end of my answer.

```
REQD_BEGIN = 15
REQD_END = 4
PERMITTED_CHARS = ('a'..'z').to_a.join
  #=> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

str = "abcdefrqsjklmnoXX_123"

nbr_replacements = str.size - REQD_BEGIN - REQD_END
  #=> 2 
available_chars =
  PERMITTED_CHARS.delete(str[0,REQD_BEGIN].downcase +
    str[-REQD_END, REQD_END].downcase)
  #=> "ghiptuvwxyz" 
str[0, REQD_BEGIN] + available_chars[0, nbr_replacements] +
  str[-REQD_END, REQD_END] 
  #=> "abcdefrqsjklmnogh_123"
```

This does not modify ("mutate) `str`. To mutate the string, change the last line to:

```
s[REQD_BEGIN, nbr_replacements] = available_chars[0, nbr_replacements]
  #=> "gh"
```

Now:

```
s #=> "abcdefrqsjklmnogh_123"
```

If the replacement characters are to be selected randomly (but satisfy the uniqueness properties set out at the onset), the constant `PERMITTED_CHARS` would be set equal to a string containing the characters from which a random sample would be drawn. `available_chars` would be computed as now, but `available_chars[0, nbr_replacements]` would be changed to `available_chars.sample(nbr_replacements)`.

Answer (score 0):

Clearest for me would be something like:

```
prefix = str[0..14]
middle = str[15..17]
suffix = str[18..-1]
unique_id = prefix + middle.next + suffix
```

If I understand right.